# PHP AES 256 encrypt weird characters

Tags: php, mysql, encryption, aes, mcrypt

I have the following encrypt code:

```
function encryptData($value){ 
   $key = "7685647tfyr65413285746352413sgfh"; 
   $text = $value; 
   $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB); 
   $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND); 
   $crypttext = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv); 
   return $crypttext; 
}

echo 'Encrpt: ' . encryptData('This is just a test');
```

The output is: **Encrpt: yUB�F3�*ľ�G-�ۅd�8�f�_�X/O**

I'm going to place this into a mySQL database but was unsure if it would accept those types of weird characters?

Am i doing this correctly?

Comment: base64_encode and addslashes it before sending it into the database

Comment: Those aren't characters. It's binary data which your output method cannot represent.  It can be store that way  in a column which accepts binary data, or you can encode it as ascii via `base64_encode()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are doing it correctly, however the output is a binary value. To be save, it's good practice to encode it to a 'regular' string via

```
$encrypted_base64 = base64_encode($crypttext);
```

Just remember to do the *opposite* before decoding;

```
$crypttext = base64_decode($encrypted_base64);
```

Comment: Yup, that should do the trick, just try it :) but also be sure to modify your *decrypt* method the same way (as mentioned)